# Question on randomized algorithm solution

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a randomised algorithm which can find a solution with probability   . You would like to run the algorithm    times and chose the best solution. What should be    so that you are sure to find at least one solution with 99.99% guarantee?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide some more details in order to make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the algorithm finds a solution for $n$ trials is the complement of the probability that it doesn't find a solution for any trials. In other words, it is $$1-(1-p)^{n}$$
Setting this equal to $0.9999$ finds $$1-(1-p)^{n} = 0.9999\rightarrow(1-p)^n = 0.0001$$

Then taking the log of both sides finds $$n\ln(1-p) = \ln(0.0001)\rightarrow n = \frac{\ln(0.0001)}{\ln(1-p)}$$

In general, if you want to succeed with probability $q$, $$n = \frac{\ln(1-q)}{\ln(1-p)}$$